# How to create a custom hash inside form_tag block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a Rails 3 app and I'm trying to create multiple db records from a a single form.

I've got a model, contents, which as attributes of body and id.  I've got a view that displays a form that lists all records and puts a checkbox next to it (and sets the value to true/checked).  A user has the option to un-select content records that they don't want.

```
<%= form_tag 'contents' do %>
  <% @contents.each do |content| %>
    <%= label_tag content.body %>
    <%= check_box_tag content.id, content.body, true %>
  <% end %>
  <br />
  <%= submit_tag "Next" %>
<% end %>
```

When this form pots, I get params that looks like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>cooltoken",
 "1"=>"asdfasfdf",
 "2"=>"asdfasdf adf",
 "3"=>"asdf asdf asdf",
 "commit"=>"Next",
 "action"=>"create",
"controller"=>"contents"}
```

But what I want is a params hash that looks like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"cooltoken",
 'user_selections' => {
                      "1"=>"asdfasfdf",
                      "2"=>"asdfasdf adf",
                      "3"=>"asdf asdf asdf",
                     } 
"commit"=>"Next",
"action"=>"create",
"controller"=>"contents"}
```

How do I push the contents info into it's own hash (that I'm calling the 'user_selection' hash above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= check_box_tag content.id, content.body, true, { name: "user_selections[#{content.id}]" } %>
```

Comment: That'll do it!  Thank you very much.